# How to send data to a second screen?

Tags: vba, ms-access, powerpoint, projector

I have an MS Access application for use in Churches. We cannot use PowerPoint for presentations because Access will have to load PowerPoint while time is a factor. I created a form with a textbox which is displayed on the second screen quite well, only that arranging it has been a hassle.

I would like to simulate the functionality of PowerPoint, but within access, so that it overlays content easily. This way, it will be easy to add animations, and arrange the content.

I have tried overlaying the desktop background and wallpaper, creating a screensaver with VBA, but none works, since I do not want to change the wallpaper of the user. I hope my question is clear, I really need help.

Comment: I really don't think Access is the tool for this - though it is not very clear to me what outcome you expect.

Comment: I can create another system altogether. What other system or tool do you think would work?        The Outcome I expect is just the ability to smoothly display slides on a second screen, using any method. With Access, you have to use a form, and I feel like it comes with limitations

Comment: I use Visual Studio when graphics are involved - but it may very well be overkill for this. But there are lots of presentation software out there.

Comment: Have you used Visual Studio to write code that can display full screen on another screen like powerpoint would do? If yes, could you share?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've used it for picture processing and editing only, not presentation.

Comment: Some points are confusing me: **/1/** "We cannot use PowerPoint . . . Access will have to load PowerPoint while time is a factor" => could perhaps be solved with something like "load into memory but hidden" and "let it show at another time". **/2/** you are speaking of a "form with a textbox", this means that you are presentation just plain text?  **/3/** When mentioning this "it overlays content easily" and "easy to add animations", I am very interested in getting something like this working in Ms Access! Could you describe an example in a few sentences?

Comment: If the issue is just _how do I open a form as full-screen on a specific screen_, then ask that, it's already a quite complicated task.

Comment: Is there any application I can create, to display content on a projector (or second screen), without using a form? (due to the limitations of a form) ... Can I simulate the functionality of powerpoint and create my own application to do the same?